# Firebase Identity Platform Release Version Authentication Problem

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, release-mode, google-cloud-identity

I wasn't having such a problem when using the old Firebase authentication methods. After accepting Identity Platform, my gmail and phone auth systems are not working in "android release" mode of my app (downloaded play store app). I'm currently search of the reason for this. I also put the sha keys to Firebase from Google Console App Signing and i also debugging authentication code base with test phone numbers and test gmails. There is no problem in code base or sha keys(my opinion). Now I am verifying oauth in Google Cloud Console. When this verification is verified, will my gmail and phone auths in android release mode be opened? And how long does this verification process take? Ios gmail and phone auth  methods work well in the apple store or emulator. Also when i look at Google Cloud Console there are some errors on Identity Toolkit Api and Token Service Api.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgGKi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeF3a.png)

I think the cause of the problem is identity platform integration and this validation for oauth. For what other reason do you think the firebase authentication systems (gmail and phone) works on iOS but not on Android?